# TypeScript is ignoring generic type when combining optional one

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

I have a problem with typing generic function and I narrowed my problem to this:

When combining generic type `A` with any regular object `B` TypeScript completely ignores generic one and treats it as `B`.

```
interface RegularObjType {
  regularKey: string;
}

interface BaseObjType {
  baseKey: string;
}

function addBasePropertyToObject<T extends { [key: string]: any }>(
  genericObj?: T,
  regularObj?: RegularObjType
) {
  const baseObject: BaseObjType | undefined = { baseKey: "baseValue" };

  const baseWithRegular = {
    ...baseObject,
    ...regularObj
  };

  const baseWithGeneric = {
    ...baseObject,
    ...genericObj
  };

  return { baseWithRegular, baseWithGeneric };
}

const {baseWithGeneric, baseWithRegular} = addBasePropertyToObject(
  { genericKey: "genericValue" },
  { regularKey: "regularValue" }
);
```

Assumed types by TypeScript:

```
// baseWithRegular type is combination of both
const baseWithRandom: {
  randomKey?: string | undefined;
  baseKey: string;
}

// baseWithGeneric type is just baseObject
const baseWithGeneric: {
  baseKey: string;
}
```

Because of that I don't have the access to keys of generic I passed to the function.

```
//                        Works
const {baseKey: baseKey1, regularKey} = baseWithRegular
//                        Property 'genericKey' does not exist on type '{ baseKey: string; }'.
const {baseKey: baseKey2, genericKey} = baseWithGeneric
```

Is there a way of getting better typing in this particular case?

Code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-stallman-bbr2ek?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: What type do you expect `baseWithGeneric` to be?  If `genericObj` is `undefined` then the output will be of type `BaseObject`, while if it is of type `T` then the output will be of type `BaseObject & T`.  If you want to see `BaseObject | (BaseObject & T)` you can annotate that, but it doesn't help you find any of `genericObj`'s keys, because it's a union.

Comment: I tried the union before, it looks intuitive but like you said it doesn't help to have `genericObj` keys. What I would like is to have `genericObj` keys as optional but be able to autocomplete them. Is there even a way to achieve it?

Comment: You can achieve anything with a type assertion, but I'm still not clear about what type you expect; can you spell it out? Is it `BaseObject & Partial<T>`? That's a little weird because the only time `T` will be inferred as anything useful is when the value is passed in, and thus the properties should be required and not optional.  I would start refactoring to something like [this](//tsplay.dev/N7O8PN) but that might not be your real use case.